# How to automatically run ECS Task when it stopes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I am looking for information about the possibility to automatically run a given ECS task when it stopes working. 
The most important thing is I want to keep only one task instance at a time (I tried to use ECS scheduler but it does not look like it is possible to achieve).
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `a service` in ECS, and fix the `Number of tasks` = 1